# Bypass country access firewall

Tags: linux, firewall, vps

I live in Iran

in Iran internet is blocked and Iranian can only access to Iran IP ranges and other ranges are blocked.

How can we bypass this ?

Do we need VPS for this ?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the purpose of serverfault: managing IT in a business environment.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is not simple because it depends how well blockade was implemented. Usually your best bet is on VPN but regime probably blocked popular services and may be monitoring traffic for common VPN protocols.

I would ask someone outside to set up VPN server for you on some random port - WireGuard for example. This gives you better chances to stay undetected.

I really sympathize with you but I can't recommend doing it as it may put you in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but they blocked our Internet based on white listing, they only white listed iranian websites and servers, how we can bypass this?